# Oracle Functionality of Insert All Into Versus By Individual Column

Tags: oracle, select, insert

I've gotten to one of those places where I've been toying with something for a little while trying to figure out why its not working and figured I would ask here. I am currently in the middle of making adjustments to a batch process that involves creating an external table A used for staging and then transferring the data from that table over to Table B for further processing.

There's a step in the batch that was there before to load all that data and it goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE B SELECT * FROM TABLE A
```

Upon running this statement in batch and outside of it in Oracle Developer I get the following error:

```
Run query ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

I went through my adjustments line by line and made sure I had the right data types. I also went over the data itself the best I could and from what I can tell it seems normal also. In an effort to find which individual field could have been having the error, I attempted to load data from Table A to Table B one column at a time...Doing this I received no errors which shocked me somewhat. If I use the SQL below and have all the fields listed out individually, the load of all the data works flawlessly. Can someone explain why this might be? Does the below function perform an internal Oracle working that the previous one does not?

```
    insert into TABLE B (
    COLUMN_ONE,
    COLUMN_TWO,
    COLUMN_THREE
    .
    .
    .)
    select
    COLUMN_ONE,
    COLUMN_TWO,
    COLUMN_THREE
    .
    .
    .
    from TABLE A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you posted description of tables A and B, we could see it ourselves. As it is now, we have to trust what you're saying, i.e. that *everything matches* (but Oracle disagrees), so I don't know what to say.

On the other hand, I've learnt that using

```
INSERT INTO TABLE B SELECT * FROM TABLE A
```

is a poor way of handling things (unless that's a *quick & dirty* testing). I try to always name all columns I'm working with, no matter how many of them are involved in that very operation. As you noticed, that seems to be working well for you too, so I'd suggest you to keep doing it.